# If $\int_{0}^{2\pi}(f(x)-\sin x)^2\,{\rm d}x$ is minimised then find the value of $f(-4\pi^2).$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

> Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function satisfying $f(\frac{x+y}{2})=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(0)=0$. If $\int_{0}^{2\pi}(f(x)-\sin x)^2\,{\rm d}x$ is minimised then find the value of $f(-4\pi^2).$

---

**My attempt:**

$f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$
$f'\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=\frac{f'(x)+f'(y)\frac{dy}{dx}}{2}$
$\int_{0}^{2\pi}(f(x)-\sin x)^2
\,{\rm d}x=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left[(f(x))^2+(\sin x)^2-2f(x)\sin x\right]{\rm d}x$
I am stuck here, I don't know how $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left[(f(x))^2+(\sin x)^2-2f(x)\sin x \right]{\rm d}x$ is to be minimised and how to find $f(-4\pi^2)$.

Comment: Under the conditions for $f$, $f(x)=my+b$ for some real constants $m,b$. So minimize the integral on $m,b$. $(b=f(0),\ m=f(1)-f(0))$.

Comment: Oops, I now see $f(0)=0$, so $f(x)=mx$ where $m=f(1)$. So this is an exercise in single-variable minimization.

Comment: Thank you very much @RoryDaulton,i got the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f(0)=0, f(x/2)=f(x)/2$ and $f$ is continuous, $f(x)=mx$. Now:

$$ \frac{d}{dm}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(mx-\sin(x))^2\,dx = \int_{0}^{2\pi}2x(mx-\sin x)\,dx $$
so the optimal $m$ is given by the solution of $3+4m\pi^2 = 0$ and that implies $f(-4\pi^2)=\color{red}{3}$.